# Do you have to create multiple header.php files to have a dynamic header?

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, header

I am trying to create a header that changes every time that a new post is created. The featured image of the newest post should also become the home page header with a button to see that post. Is it best practice to have multiple header.php files or should I have one with conditional statements?

Comment: One with conditions, or maybe _one with the universe padawan learner_

Comment: Make one only, create a function to get the picture from the newest post.If you wanna get annoying, change the pictures with AJAX (without reloading the page) . It's pointless to use PHP if you decide the functionality to be like in a 100% HTML site :) .

Comment: @MarinNedea So I did what you said, but my issue is that I am changing all of the headers. I guess that I am struggling to use is_home() in the html to set my if statement.

Comment: @rabowlen you should let us see some code sample. We don't know how you're website works, how is built, etc. without some sample codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a multuple dynamic header. You need one header for your post. Let's say for instance, you have

post.php

in the post.php file you might need something like include "header.php". In the include try the following

```
//put this portion of the code in between the head tag somewhere

<!--Little CSS fade in -->
<style>
.fade-in{
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  -moz-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -ms-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -o-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@-o-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!--We appendin' on this div - ps: ids make sense here... punk-->
<div id="banner-load"></div>

<!--Don't forget Jquery-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'></script>

<!--New images on load -->
<script>
//Add your images, we'll set the path in the next step
    var images = ['banner-1.jpg', 'banner-2.jpg', 'banner-3.jpg', 'banner-4.jpg];

//Build the img, then do a bit of maths to randomize load and append to a div. Add a touch off css to fade them badboys in all sexy like.
    $('<img class="fade-in" src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner-load');
</script>

</body>
?>
```

Make sure in the includes to remember where the head tags and body tags are when including files.

Here is a link to the github https://gist.github.com/stephenscaff/8266351